# Bootstrap tiered radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm fairly new to jQuery, and currently learning it, so please forgive me if what I'm asking is so ridiculous.

I'm creating a web-form in using Bootstrap which uses radio buttons and is tiered, so when you select "Yes" for the first option, it will display the next set of radio buttons, then when you select "Yes" for that option it will show a text box.

Here is my current HTML.

```
<div class="from-group row">

                    <div class="col-sm-6 wireless_use">
                        <label for="wireless_use" name="wireless_use" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-form-label">Used any wireless bridge kit?</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="wireless_use1" id="wireless_use" value="1"> Yes
                            </label>

                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="wireless_use0" id="wireless_use" value="0"> No
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 hidden wireless_use_yes">
                        <label for="wireless_use_yes" name="wireless_use_yes" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-form-label">Did you have any problems?</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="wireless_use_yes1" id="wireless_use_yes" value="1"> Yes
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="wireless_use_yes0" id="wireless_use_yes" value="0"> No
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group row hidden wireless_use_yes_problems">
                    <label for="wireless_use_yes_problems" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">What problems did you have?</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="wireless_use_yes_problems" placeholder=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my CSS relevant to this:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("name") == "wireless_use1") {
        $(".wireless_use_yes").show();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("name") == "wireless_use_yes1") {
        $(".wireless_use_yes").show();
        $(".wireless_use_yes_problems").show();

    }
});

$('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');  // trigger the event
```

});

Any help or advice with this issue is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For selecting any input with particular name with jQuery we use

```
[name="xyz"]
```

In your case is must be

```
$("input[name='wireless_use1']")
```

If you want to trigger an event on change the it must be like

```
$("input[name='wireless_use1']").change(function(){...});
```

I have created a fiddle for your problem i hope this will help you resolve your isse.

[Fiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ngd4jdzc/1/)

-Help :)